# Searching for multiple keywords listed in the buffer

Tags: search

Given two buffers, where

the **first** one has a **list of keywords** delimited by a new line;

the **second** buffer with **text** that contains a subset of keywords from the first buffer.

How do I search and highlight all these words from the first buffer in the second buffer?

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
:match Search /\V\<\(^R=EXPRESSION\)\>/
```

Where `^R` is input with `^V^R` and `EXPRESSION` is `join(getbufline('#', 1, '$'), '\|')` and `#` is your buffer holding "keyword list" one per line (for simplicity I also assume that no keyword contains "slash" or "backslash").

For something more substantial you should probably build custom syntax with `syntax keyword`, `readfile()`, `execute` etc.

Comment: Expanding on your answer: `:execute 'match Search /\V\<\('.getbufline('#', 1, '$')->map({s -> s->escape('/\')})->join('\|').'\)\>/'`. Uses `:execute` to build the command from a string, groups the list of words with `\(...\)`, escapes them with `escape()` and gets them from buffer `#` (last buffer.) Also, perhaps using anchors `^` and `$` instead is what the OP wanted? From the description, it's one word per line apparently... Should be an easy fix. Great answer!

Comment: @filbranden Thank you. `execute` is good for scripts but if the command is expected to run interactively then the expression register is easier to write and debug, IMO. Also I'd like to avoid "method" notation, as it's not supported by Neovim, and so `join(map(getbufline(...), {->escape(...)}, '...')` could become too difficult to read and understand. Anyway, I believe, there's little chance that any "keyword" contains slash.

Comment: Why not `call matchadd('Search', join(getbufline('#',1,'$'),'\|'))` (it can get more complicated, e.g. by adding word-boundaries, escaping special characters, etc), but that would be my basic idea.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Well, no special counter-argument, except maybe `:match NONE` looks to me more natural and precise than `call clearmatches()`. Also, I consider this as an interactive command (thinking of "keyword" buffer being opened in the current Vim session), not a standalone script.